# How to find a truck mechanic while traveling in New Zealand

Tags: online-resources, automobiles, new-zealand, wellington

We are traveling through New Zealand for 8 months and bought a Motorhome that is built onto a 1994 Ford Trader Diesel truck.

We are on our way to the South island and appear to have an oil leak and want to get it fixed before we cross over.

How does one go about finding a good mechanic in Wellington?

There is Yelp and TripAdvisor for typical traveling searches, how would a kiwi find good services?

We have never owned a truck before and google searches don't appear to be helping.

There are some sites: localist, nocowboys, trademe but it is hard to know if they are for real or not.

Comment: Not sure that this is even related to travel.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about living in New Zealand.

Comment: I edited the question to be more clear, we are on the road in New Zealand and need car help.

Comment: Awesome!  Is that what kiwis use? Localist?

Comment: Most businesses of that type are probably listed in the yellow pages, at http://yellow.co.nz/ however that won't help you filter them based on quality.

I'd suggest you phone up some businesses in the Wellington region that obviously own trucks, and ask them if they can recommend a mechanic.

(Would have posted this as an answer, but was too slow and the question got closed while I wrote my answer! A shame, as I think the rewording makes it worthy of staying open.)

Comment: I reworded it again in hopes of keeping it open. And made it more general to new zealand. I found a site called nocowboys, but is it a scam?

Comment: @Karlson do questions ever get re-evaluated? There are a few here that believe it is on topic after the edits.

Comment: @digidigo They do.  There is a method to reopen the question, which yours is one vote away from being reopened.

Comment: I'm sure you've solved your issue now, but this will be a good resource for any future reference... perhaps ask someone on the Wellington Community Noticeboard: https://www.facebook.com/groups/ProudWellingtonians/

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 3):

I would ask on one of the motorhome forms, e.g. http://www.nzmotorhome.co.nz/NZMotorhome/index.html

Comment: Probably best as a comment, but as a new user he can't comment. @mindcorrosive?

Comment: The question is "How does one go about finding a good mechanic in Wellington?" and specifically relates to a motorhome. The answer directs the user to a specific motorhome forum where people with that knowledge (who are unlikely to be on S/E) reside. How is that not an answer? They said Google searches haven't helped and they don't know whether the other standard sites (No Cowboys, etc) are reliable. When you want someone reliable you have to go by people's first-hand experience, which is available by asking on a specialist forum.

Comment: For what it is worth, I did try this route. But did not get any response on the forum.